# Can I build C++ on Debian?

Tags: debian, software-development

I would like to program, build and run C++ software from a single interface.

Can I build C++ on Debian? Does there exist an IDE for Debian on the Raspberry Pi, in which I can develop C++?

Comment: What do you mean "the" C++ program?

Comment: It cannot be determined what you are asking in this question. What C++ program? What are you expecting? What is your outcome? Please review your question and add more details. For now it will be closed.

Comment: Reopened. Good job making this a valuable contribution to the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, use `g++`.

As for an IDE, I use `vim` and [Unix is an IDE](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/series/unix-as-ide/).

Comment: I prefer emacs. But which one is better? There's only one way to find out! Fiiigggghhhhttttt!